# Allow for a given number of failures in array comparison

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I've created some unit tests where I generate some time series data and run two different estimations that should be roughly equal using the generated data. When I inspect the result visually, it looks like everything is working fine for most data points but with a few larger errors.

Right now, I have comparison set up using `verifyEqual` to test if they match. In order to deal with this, I've had to increase the tolerances on `verifyEqual` to be larger than I think is reasonable. I'd like to set up a test where I check if more than 95% of the elements of the array satisfy the tolerances given.

For example, the following test fails:

```
array1 = (1:100)';
array2 = array1 + rand(100, 1) ./ 100 + [zeros(4,1); .5; zeros(95,1)];

testCase = matlab.unittest.TestCase.forInteractiveUse;
testCase.verifyEqual(array1, array2, 'AbsTol', 0.01)
```

In this context, I'm ok with one element being outside the tolerance, but I'd be concerned if it was more than 5 elements that failed.

Is there a better way to run this test within the Matlab unit testing framework than `testCase.verifyLessThanOrEqual(sum(abs(array1 - array2) >= 0.01), 5)`, i.e., one that gives informative failure output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is not a tolerance in the test framework to provide this functionality, but I think its an interesting and good use case. I will create an enhancement request to provide a tolerance like this.

In the meantime, however, you can create your own tolerance to do this. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-custom-tolerance.html) is the documentation which describes how to do this. Basically it involves writing a `supports` method which is passed a value and determines whether the tolerance can apply to the value. Then you need to implement a `satisfiedBy` method which takes the two values being compared and determined whether they are within the tolerance. Finally you'll need to implement a `getDiagnosticFor` method to  return a diagnostic that gives you all of that informative output. Here's something to get you started:

```
classdef ForgivingAbsoluteTolerance < matlab.unittest.constraints.Tolerance

    properties
        % QualityRequired - percent of the compared array that needs to be
        % within the specified tolerance
        QualityRequired = 0.95; 
        AbsTolValue;
    end

    methods
        function tolerance = ForgivingAbsoluteTolerance(absTol, quality)
            tolerance.AbsTolValue = absTol;
            if nargin > 1
                tolerance.QualityRequired = quality;
            end
        end

        function tf = supports(~, value)
            tf = isnumeric(value);
        end

        function tf = satisfiedBy(tolerance, actual, expected)
            withinTolerance = findWithinTolerance(actual, expected, tolerance.AbsTolValue);
            tf = nnz(withinTolerance) >= numel(expected)*tolerance.QualityRequired;
        end


        function diag = getDiagnosticFor(tolerance, actual, expected)
            import matlab.unittest.diagnostics.StringDiagnostic;

            withinTolerance = findWithinTolerance(actual, expected, tolerance.AbsTolValue);
            numValuesOutsideTolerance = nnz(~withinTolerance);
            str = [...
                num2str(numValuesOutsideTolerance) ' values were found outside of the tolerance value of ' num2str(tolerance.AbsTolValue), newline, ...
                'The tolerance''s quality of ' num2str(tolerance.QualityRequired) ' allows ' num2str(floor(numel(expected)*(1-tolerance.QualityRequired))) ' elements to be outside of the tolerance.', newline, ...
                '    Failing Indices: ' mat2str(find(~withinTolerance))];
            diag = StringDiagnostic(str);
        end
    end
end

function mask = findWithinTolerance(actual,expected, tolerance)
mask = abs(expected - actual) <= tolerance;
mask = mask(:).'; % make a row for better mat2str output
end
```

This is just a start. With a little more time/effort you can make the diagnostics better. However, once you write this, you can reuse it by issuing the following call:

```
testCase.verifyThat(array1, IsEqualTo(array2, 'Within', ));


>> array1 = (1:100)';
>> array2 = array1 + rand(100, 1) ./ 100 + [zeros(4,1); .5; zeros(95,1)];

>> testCase = matlab.unittest.TestCase.forInteractiveUse;
>> testCase.verifyThat(array1, IsEqualTo(array2, 'Within', ForgivingAbsoluteTolerance(0.01)))
Interactive verification passed.

>> % now let's see a failing one.
>> array2 = array1 + rand(100, 1) ./ 100 + [zeros(4,1); ones(6,1)*.5; zeros(90,1)];
>> testCase.verifyThat(array1, IsEqualTo(array2, 'Within', ForgivingAbsoluteTolerance(0.01)))
Interactive verification failed.

---------------------
Framework Diagnostic:
---------------------
IsEqualTo failed.
--> NumericComparator failed.
    --> The values are not equal using "isequaln".
    --> 6 values were found outside of the tolerance value of 0.01
        The tolerance's quality of 0.95 allows 5 elements to be outside of the tolerance.
            Failing Indices: [5 6 7 8 9 10]

    Actual double:
        100x1 double
    Expected double:
        100x1 double
>>
```